# Lotus Notes - New Action on All Inboxes

Tags: lotus-notes

I would like to introduce a new action to all inboxes on Lotus Notes (e.g. Report Email) alongside 'New Message', 'Reply', 'Forward' etc.

I have entered the design mode of an existing sub folder, written and tested the Action using LotusScript.

How can this be implemented globally? i.e. to all email users

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you a Domino admin? If yes, then the task can be done like this:

- Open mailX.ntf from local or server
- Create new copy of mailX.ntf on your Client
- Change the template name (properties, the tab with the ruler) of the new mailXcopy.ntf
- Modify the template as desired
- replicate the template to the server
- use the convert- tool to replace the template of all or selected mailfiles

Take care: Especially the last step can lead to empty inboxes or missing mails in inboxes if not done properly. Better ask someone who knows how to do this.